# Value not retained for action parameter when inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2, commandlink, uirepeat

Below is my Code:

```
<ui:repeat var="status" value="#{showUpdatedAction.statusUpdates}">
    <h:panelGroup>
    #{status.content}
        <h:form> 
           <h:commandLink value="Like" action="#{statusAction.likeStatus(status.id,1)}" />
        </h:form>
  </h:panelGroup>
<ui:repeat>
```

`#{status.content}` shows correct values. When I print id of status using `#{status.id}`, it also gives correct value. But when I click the command link, value passed is always 0 for status.id.

Can someone tell me why this happens and how can I avoid this?

Thank you.

**Edit 1**

Interestingly, when instead of passing the parameter in function, I pass it using `<f:param>`, it works perfectly. Can anyone comment on that?

Comment: This should work. Show the *smallest possible* but *complete* view (from `<html>` until `</html>`) and bean code which reproduces for you exactly this problem and please mention the exact JSF impl/version and server impl/version used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `<c:forEach>` instead of `<ui:repeat>`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly, why `status.id` is 0 in your case but you can directly pass the whole `status` object in your EL expression. Like so:

```
<h:commandAction value="Like" action="#{statusAction.likeStatus(status)}" />
```

Then in your `likeStatus` you simply do a `int statusId = status.getId()` or similar and you have what you want.

As an addition: Using `<c:forEach>` should actually be just a fallback, because people say you shouldn't mix JSTL with JSF for whatsoever reasons.

Comment: When I sent whole status object, I got an object with all its values set to null.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the JSF page is just fine, just checked it... (generated the beans at my side too : showUpdatedAction, statusAction , and  a simple class Status)

```
public void likeStatus(String id,long someVal){
    System.out.println(id+"___"+someVal);
}
```

which prints the ids just fine

id1___1

id4___1

Maybe its something to do with the type of the id or something with your beans?

Comment: I have tried changing the type too, but it is not working for me.

Comment: try changing you JSF implementation jar , try mojarra 2.03 (that's the one i tried)

Comment: don't know what it could be, but if you want i can send you my small project in which i made it work, so you hopefully can find the problem... Or maybe generate 2 beans + 1 class with minimum code and see if it works well for you